# SAP Cloud SDK OData V4 Support

Tags: java, sap-cloud-sdk

it is possible to call OData Service V4 from the SAP Cloud SDK? I could only find tutorials from SAP which are consuming V2. I the documentation i could not find the information. In my case it will be an custom OData Service V4 which will be generated through the OData VMD Generator.

Best regards, 
Manjinder Singh

Comment: As Alexander writes below, OData v4 services are not supported today by the VDM generator. Could you let us know a few details about your OData v4 service (how has it been created, in which kind of system is it exposed), so that we can consider this for potentially expanding the generator in the future?

Comment: Hi, if we are looking at the Roadmap of the ABAP Restful Programmiung model it is a feature in the future to support OData V4. (see https://help.sap.com/doc/59d5e6b765eb49c5884a94de512e8259/LATEST/en-US/ABAP_RESTful_Programming_Model.pdf). Maybe you could consider it in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for the question. Unfortunately the SAP Cloud SDK and its OData VDM generator does not support OData V4.

Answer (score 2):

OData V4 is now documented here: https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/odata/generate-typed-odata-v2-and-v4-client-for-java ;-)